# how to get the bluetooth address of my own device in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, mobile-development

There are many packages in Flutter dealing with things related to Bluetooth but none of them enables me to see the Bluetooth address of my own device, does anyone know to do that?
thank you in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most mobile operating systems rate the use of BD_ADDR, from the application level, as bad behavior (many applications used this ID to track the user).
That is why modern mobile operating systems prevent you from doing this.